# How can I know when user going to clear cache of my app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm new to Phonegap, I need to know when user going to clear cache of installed app or can we take control on user mobile like examples on to know about charging of mobile,clear cache etc... belongs to my app...

plz help on this,

Thanking you,

Comment: I don't understand.. do you want them to call you saying "Hey, heads up I'm clearing the app cache!"?

Comment: ha,yes looking for that..

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to be alerted when a user is going to clear your app cache. However, you can place a file in the cache and every time the app is opened, check to see if that file exists. If it doesn't exist, then you know the user cleared the cache and you can take appropriate action, including placing the file back in the cache.

Comment: can you plzz.. tell me how can I implement it in phonegap